# 「ついでの」in this context

Tags: translation

I know 「ついで」like in 「〜るついでに」, but don't know what to make of it in this context:

あと何年かしたらきっとついでのチョコになっちゃうんだろうけどね。

The context is of a girl getting some Valetine's Day Chocolate.

I would think of it as "Only some more years and you'll eventually turn into a ??? chocolate"

Comment: I'm only 70% sure about the meaning of ついで in this sentence. Could you add some more context, perhaps a few more sentences before and after this one? And a girl *getting* chocolate is not very common in Japan.

Comment: It's a girl making chocolate for her big sister. Before that the big sister says 「ていうか　あたしはこんな幸せでいいんだろうか‥」. And after that the friend says (the same one who says the above) 「ほんとだよ、いいよね…」And adds what I wrote above as an afterthought. The big sister gets angry as a result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> あと何年かしたらきっとついでのチョコになっちゃうんだろうけどね。
>   Several years from now, this chocolate will be "ついでの" chocolate, though.

ついでのチョコ roughly means "chocolate prepared since she was preparing chocolate for someone else", "chocolate not made for the primary purpose", etc. This sentence means that, several years later, the girl would be preparing chocolate mainly for someone else whom she loves, and preparing chocolate for her elder sister only as the secondary purpose.

See: [Difference between ついでに and たびに in the following example](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29286/5010)

In Japanese Valentine's day culture, there is something called 本命チョコ and 義理チョコ.

[Valentine's Day, Japan: A How-to Guide](https://www.tofugu.com/japan/valentines-day-japan/)

> #### GIRI-CHOCOLATE (義理チョコ)
>
> Giri-Chocolate means “obligatory chocolate.” This kind of chocolate refers to the chocolate you have to give to people (who aren’t really people you love). These could be people like bosses, coworkers, male friends, etc.
>
> #### HONMEI-CHOCOLATE (本命チョコ)
>
> Honmei-Chocolate means “favorite chocolate.” This kind of chocolate is the kind of chocolate you give to the one you want to express your love to. These chocolates tend to be more expensive or possibly even home made.

So the friend is saying the girls is making 本命チョコ for her sister for now, but it would be 義理チョコ in the near future.

Comment: Wow, this is surprisingly sophisticated