# what does 急ぐついでに mean?

Tags: grammar

This phrase appears in the first episode of the anime Acchi Kocchi:

> **急ぐついでに**早く行って暖房の恩恵にすがろうかと

What does this 急ぐついでに mean?

Answer (score 4):

ついで is a noun that is a bit difficult to translate by itself, but it refers to "a secondary/side purpose". ついでに is often translated as "while you're at it" or "taking this opportunity". ついで can be safely modified by a relative clause.

- [Difference between ついでに and たびに in the following example](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29286/5010)
- [「ついでの」in this context](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40579/5010)
- [Maggie Sensei: How to use ついでに (=tsuideni)](http://maggiesensei.com/2015/01/14/how-to-use-%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AB-tsuideni/)

In this sentence, the speaker will hurry (急ぐ) primarily for something mentioned in the previous sentences, and the 暖房 is the secondary purpose.

Comment: "While you're at it" is probably the most natural translation.