# ゴミ、捨てに行くけど、ついでに、これも捨ててこようか

Tags: meaning, conversations

> ゴミ、捨てに行くけど、ついでに、これも捨ててこようか
>
> a-うん、お願い
> b-うん、捨てるよ

I am wondering why is a correct and b wrong.
As far as I know よう is a  誘い・提案 - invitation, suggestion for 一緒にする.
so is the replying person saying yes go and throw it out, or yes, I will throw this out also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

よう has many meanings, and it can indicate the speaker's own will, too. For example 海に行こう(か) can mean either "Let's go to the sea (together)" and "(Okay) I'll go to the sea" depending on the context.

So you should check the previous context:

> ゴミ、捨てに行くけど、ついでに

Clearly, the first speaker is the one who's doing ゴミ捨て, and [ついでに](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/78789/5010) indicates the first speaker is thinking of doing another thing while doing so. In this context, これも捨ててこようか only means "should/will **I** ～?".